# Toggle text on click on a query loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a section that lists content on a query and ends with a link that changes it's name upon click. In this context, 'objetos' displays data from a class that I then turn to html.

```
{% for i in objetos %}
...
<a onclick="change()" id="{{i.id}}">Fav</a>
    <script>
        function change() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("{{i.id}}");
            if (elem.innerHTML == "Fav")
                elem.innerHTML = "Unfav";
            else
                elem.innerHTML = 'Fav';
            }
    </script>
...
{% endfor %}
```

However the script seems to only load the last value of 'i', and so only the last link changes. Do I have to save it every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this.

```
{% for i in objetos %}
...
<a onclick="change(this)" id="{{i.id}}">Fav</a>
...
{% endfor %}

<script>
    function change(e) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(e.getAttribute('id'))
        if (elem.innerHTML == "Fav")
            elem.innerHTML = "Unfav";
        else
            elem.innerHTML = 'Fav';
        }
</script>
```

Your actual rendered code is this.

```
...
<a onclick="change()" id="1">Fav</a>
    <script>
        function change() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("1");
            if (elem.innerHTML == "Fav")
                elem.innerHTML = "Unfav";
            else
                elem.innerHTML = 'Fav';
            }
    </script>
...

...
<a onclick="change()" id="2">Fav</a>
    <script>
        function change() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("2");
            if (elem.innerHTML == "Fav")
                elem.innerHTML = "Unfav";
            else
                elem.innerHTML = 'Fav';
            }
    </script>
...

...
<a onclick="change()" id="3">Fav</a>
    <script>
        function change() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("3");
            if (elem.innerHTML == "Fav")
                elem.innerHTML = "Unfav";
            else
                elem.innerHTML = 'Fav';
            }
    </script>
...
```

Inspect on browser. You will see this.

So when you click on first  the last   gets called as it matches the js function name.  **If you create multiple js function name with same name, last function would be use** *It's same as reassgning value*
Same way in your code the last function was getting called always. Hence was the issue.

Comment: it worked, thanks! At first I was thinking the problem was I was searching for {{i.id}} and so I kept the script inside the loop, but that since I only executed when the loop ended the value of 'i' would always be the last one. It seems it might have had something to do with it but I also totally forgot about the name of the function. Thanks!